# How to determine number of write transactions per second in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to measure how many **write** transactions are happening per second in Postgres? As I understand `pg_stat_database.xact_commit` will show **total** number of transactions committed, but I want to exclude readonly queries and only see the number of commits that actually modified data.

Comment: You can get the number of /tuples/ updated (`pg_stat_database.tup_updated`), but I don't know of any way of getting the number of transactions that caused a "modification".   I'm not even sure that's really well defined and /there are a lot more transactions going on in PostgreSQL than you probably think/.   Why do you need this statistic?

Answer (score 2):

Run

```
SELECT txid_current();
```

to get the current transaction number.

If you do that at two points in time and subtract the numbers, you know how many transactions (committed or rolled back) have occurred in the mean time.

Read-only transactions do not consume a transaction ID.

Comment: Note that `txid_current()` is now [deprecated in favor of `pg_current_xact_id()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#id-1.5.8.32.35.2.2.1.1.1.1). Also, the `*_if_assigned()` variant is preferable as it won't consume a transaction ID if none is running.

Comment: @Matthieu As soon as the old function doesn't work on new releases, the answer should be updated. You need to consume a transaction if you want to know where the counter is currently.

Comment: indeed it makes sense... But I'm confused with [`pg_current_xact_id_if_assigned()` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#id-1.5.8.32.31.2.2.2.1.1.1) specifying *It's best to use this variant (...) to avoid unnecessary consumption of an XID*. Would it return 0 if there are no transaction running?

Comment: @Matthieu That's something you can easily try yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This script can be used to count number of transaction commits performed between starting the script and killing it: https://gist.github.com/dmos62/aa754a04ff8bf36d6565d74b2dad6513

Usage looks like this:

```
./count_txs.sh psql postgresql://x:y@z:1234/w
ctrl-c to stop counting
^C
55
```

This means that 55 transaction commits have been performed between starting the script and killing it.